# C++ / OpenCV IplImage* memory leakage

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-management, memory-leaks, iplimage

I am creating a visual panel that is consistent of one large (IplImage*) over which a method iterates to place into relative positions updates of a graph.

it looks like this

[image: visual panel for graphs that are updated each iteration]

in the code, each iteration, these "placeholders" / "slots" are updated with a corresponding graph image (from a plotting object which creates an image) at a corresponding position (positions are created and placed into a map relative to how many graphs I am plotting)

The reason I do not directly plot onto the panel is because I constructed this panel such that it accepts and displays any IplImage to place into a "slot", which I do later on.

I know that IplImages are outdated and horrible on memory management if not correctly released, however, I am using a library which uses the old opencv, so for convenience of everything (because I've attempted to convert everything to Mat, but that complicates things more), I continue with IplImages

I've located where things go wrong, and that is here:

```
void RsPanel::updateComponents()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < totalspots; i++) {

        CvRect rectangle = cvRect(positionMap[i].x, positionMap[i].y, slotSize.width, slotSize.height);
        cvSetImageROI(window, rectangle);

        img = slots[i].getImage();
        cvCopy(img, window);
        cvResetImageROI(window);
    }


    cvShowImage(name, window);
```

more precisely here:

```
img = slots[i].getImage();
```

from what I understand, the memory leakage results from not releasing the previous "img" properly, however when i use cvReleaseImage to release, things just crash (because from what I understand, it needs to be done after I am done with using the image.

[image: similar to this]

I have tried releasing "img" and cvCloneImage-ing the one from the slot (slots[i]->getImage()), however this gives me the same memory problem

without releasing, within a minute, the program accumulates to 1.7GB of RAM, and gives me a cv out of memory error.

The way I do it, I suppose, is not the most efficient, but my struggles with memory management (coming from a Java background) are still in need of their learning moments

Any tips to approach this?

Thank you in advance!